# Clarification needed in JUnit5 TestInfo's getTestClass()

Tags: unit-testing, junit, tdd, junit5, junit5-extension-model

fellow Coders.
The getTestClass() of JUnit5's TestInfo returns an 'Optional'. This has me wondering a scenario that would return an Optional.empty().
(Link to TestInfo documentation: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestInfo.html#getTestClass--)

Apparently I'm yet to figure it out, so I need help guys.